# Retrieve model of element

Tags: sapui5

I have a model:

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "code":"001",
            "type":"driver""descr":"AAA"
        },
        {
            "code":"002",
            "type":"article",
            "descr":"BBB"
        },
        {
            "code":"003",
            "type":"article",
            "descr":"ABBB"
        },
        {
            "code":"004",
            "type":"article",
            "descr":"BBB"
        }
    ]
}
```

I bind it in my tile container that contain sone tiles https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardTile.html. I map model "code" to "number" of tile and model "descr" to "title".

Ok, I show the tile fine.
Now I want manage the behavior when I press a tile. I want diversify the behavior: if the tile have type article I do an action, if the tile have type driver I do another action.
How can I retrieve the information that I not map in the view? How can I retrieve the model of tile??

Answer (score 0):

I'm note quite sure I know what you want, but if you only want to access the data that is bound the the tile, you can just retrieve the binding-context from the event source.

In the event-handler you can just call getSource() on the event and then get the binding-Context of that source (the tile).

Something like this:

```
oTile.attachPress(function(oEvent) {
  var oTileData = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject();
});
```